# Dependency Tracking function

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, cascade

I just wonder if anyone knows how to automatize views creation after running `DROP ... CASCADE`?
Now I'm trying to drop view at first with classic `DROP VIEW myview` statement and if I cannot drop the view because other objects still depend on it then checking out all the objects names that postgres lists and save their creates and then I run drop with cascade. Sometimes it's like over a dozen objects. But maybe you have got some idea to handle this issue in more automated way?

Maybe anybody has got some function?

Answer (score 2):

Next step... (continuation of my previous answer).

function **save_views(objectname text)** stores views depending on **objectname** (view or table) in table **saved_views**.

function **restore_views()** restores views from table **saved_views**.

```
create or replace function save_views_oid(objectid oid)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    r record;
begin
    for r in
        select distinct c.oid, c.relname, n.nspname
        from pg_depend d
        join pg_rewrite w on w.oid = d.objid
        join pg_class c on c.oid = w.ev_class
        join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
        where d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass 
        and d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass
        and d.refobjid = objectid
        and c.oid <> objectid
    loop
        insert into saved_views values (
            'CREATE VIEW ' || r.nspname || '.' || r.relname ||
            ' AS ' || pg_get_viewdef(r.oid, 'f'));
        perform save_views_oid(r.oid);
    end loop;
end; $$;

create or replace function save_views(objectname text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    create table if not exists saved_views(viewbody text);
    truncate saved_views;
    perform save_views_oid(objectname::regclass);
end; $$;

create or replace function restore_views()
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    viewtext text;
begin
    for viewtext in
        select viewbody from saved_views
    loop
        execute viewtext;
    end loop;
    drop table saved_views;
end; $$;
```

Test:

```
select save_views('my_view'); -- may be save_views('my_schema.my_view');
select * from saved_views;
```

Use:

```
select save_views('my_view'); 
drop view my_view cascade;
create view my_view as ...
select restore_views();
```

Answer (score 0):

Table [pg_depend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-depend.html) contains all necessary informations, but it is not so easy to interpret them. Here you have sketch recursive function to retrieve dependencies of pg_class object in text format. You can tune up the function to your needs (and show us results:).

```
create or replace function dependency
    (class_id regclass, obj_id regclass, obj_subid integer, dep_type "char")
returns setof text language plpgsql as $$
declare
    r record;
begin
    return query 
        select pg_describe_object(class_id, obj_id, obj_subid)
            || ' ('|| dep_type|| ')';
    for r in
        select classid, objid, objsubid, deptype
        from pg_depend
        where class_id = refclassid
        and obj_id = refobjid
        and (obj_subid = refobjsubid or obj_subid = 0)
    loop
        return query select dependency(r.classid, r.objid, r.objsubid, r.deptype);
    end loop;
end; $$;

use:

select dependency('pg_class'::regclass, 'my_view'::regclass, 0, ' ');
select dependency('pg_class'::regclass, 'my_table'::regclass, 0, ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's basically the same as a notice I get after using drop on view with dependency issue.Besides names of views are duplicated...

Comment: It's just a first step. I was hoping you could do the next ;)