# Postgres: Replace a view that has dependencies

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, ddl

I haven't found an elegant solution for this, so I wonder if someone else stumbled upon something similar.

In Postgres, I have a view `MyViewA` that is used by `MyViewB` that is used by `MyViewC`. As a performance improvement, I'd like to materialize the view A, but I can't find a simple way to do this without dropping and re-defining the entire sequence of dependencies.

That is, ideally, I would like to do this:

```
REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW MyViewA AS SELECT...
```

But unfortunately Postgres does not allow for `REPLACE` and `MATERIALIZED` in the same context. I tried just `DROP VIEW` and then `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW`, but that of course causes Postgres to complain that it `cannot drop view MyViewA because other objects depend on it`

Any advice?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14567100/1995738) may interest you.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to create a temporary view, modify `MyViewB` to use that, redefine original view and modify `MyViewB` back to original, or if there will be no queries to `MyViewA`, just rename it, define a new one and change `MyViewB`.

So assume the original is (very much simplified):

```
CREATE VIEW MyViewA AS SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table;
CREATE VIEW MyViewB AS SELECT col1, col2 FROM MyViewA where col3=1;
CREATE VIEW MyViewC AS SELECT col1 FROM MyViewB where col2='test';
```

Then you could modify `MyViewA` like this:

```
ALTER VIEW MyViewA RENAME TO MyViewTmp;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MyViewB AS SELECT col1, col2 FROM MyViewTmp where col3=1;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MyViewA AS SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MyViewB AS SELECT col1, col2 FROM MyViewA where col3=1;
DROP VIEW MyViewTmp;
```

This way you don't need to handle any dependent views.