# How do I generate a list of views dependent on a certain table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, rdbms

I need to update a mapping table in postgresql, but of course it won't allow me to replace/drop the original table as there are dependencies.

The error message details does list the dependent views, but I'd like to generate a list programmatically so that I can make temp views while I drop my original mapping table and migrate the views back afterwards.

Prefer not to do this in SQL Shell incidentally. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [Dependency Tracking function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567100/1995738)